# Symfony 6.1 Ignoring Controller and the routes inside it

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm converting a Symfony 3.4 site to 6.1. I created a brand new 6.1 site and am copying elements over 1-by-1. I'm using Attributes to define routes inside Controllers (no changes to routing.yaml).

I was working on some fixes in the CustomerController, when suddenly I started getting `route does not exist` errors for the routes inside that Controller. All other routes are working perfectly. Routes within this Controller were previously working perfectly.

I ran `bin/console debug:router` and sure enough, the routes inside the CustomerController are missing. However, the CustomerController.php file is still there, it has the correct permissions, as far as I can tell there are no syntax errors, but even if there were, I should be able to see the syntax errors instead of `route does not exist` errors, no?

As far as I can tell, Symfony is simply ignoring the existence of the CustomerController.php file. How can that be? How can I get it to include it again?

I have run `bin/console cache:clear` but it had no effect on this.

EDIT: I deliberately introduced a syntax error into the CustomerController.php file and refreshed the page in the browser, sure enough Symfony showed me the syntax error. I fixed the syntax error and the error went back to `route does not exist` - even though the route does exist in the CustomerController.php file and was previously working.

There is no further information in the log file other than the missing route exception.

EDIT2: Here's the first route and function in the Controller:

```
    #[Route('/sales/customer', name: 'customer')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('customer/list.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'CustomerController',
            'list' => 'customer'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with the first part of your CustomerController code?  Just enough to show the attributes for the first route.  Attributes have their own sub-system for processing so it's possible a syntax error is slipping through.  And just to verify, your working controllers are using attributes as well and you are using the default 6.1 routing files?

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch the links as a loop inside you template file (Twig). Something like this:

```
{% for post in posts %}  
        <a href={{ path('post_show', {'id' : post.id}) }}> 
                <p>Anytext here</p>
        </a> 
{% endfor %}
```

Any list will appear?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to reverse out the changes I had been making, and saw that I had deleted `use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;` - putting this back solved the problem! Shame that Symfony can't alert you to this kind of problem...